# Can a polynomial of the form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, where $a_k=\pm1$, have arbitrarily many distinct real roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Can a polynomial of the form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$, where $a_k=\pm1$, have arbitrarily many distinct real roots?

I suspect the answer is yes. So far, the most roots of such a polynomial that I have found, is five:  $x^{13}+x^{12}-x^{11}-x^{10}-x^9-x^8-x^7+x^6+x^5-x^4+x^3-x^2+x+1$.

(This question was inspired by a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673941/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-distinct-real-roots-of-a-polynomial-whose-coeffici/4676358#4676358), "What is the maximum number of distinct real roots of a polynomial whose coefficients are all $1$, $-1$ or $0$?")

Comment: Doesn't Sil's construction of $f(x) = x^2 - x - 1$ in the linked problem work directly? You can check that $f(x), f(x) f(x^3) = g(x), g(x)g(x^9)=h(x), \ldots$  works. Alternatively, take $ f(x), f(x) f(x^3), f(x)f(x^3)f(x^9), \ldots$, where the coefficient could be figured out by looking at the ternary expansion.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah, yes! I didn't realize that all the coefficients in Sil's construction starting with $f(x) = x^2 - x - 1$ are all $\pm1$ (no $0$ coefficients). That answers my question.

Comment: @Gonçalo What I mean is, for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a polynomial of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ where $a_k=\pm 1$, such that the polynomial has at least $m$ distinct real roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Sil's answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4676358/398708), and Calvin Lin's comment:

Let $f(x)=x^2-x-1$.

The polynomial $g(x)=f(x)f(x^3)f(x^9)...f(x^{(3^m)})$ is of the form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ where $a_k=\pm1$.

By increasing $m$, $g(x)$ can have arbitrarily many distinct real roots (as proved by Sil's answer).

Comment: Why does Sil's answer say -1, 0, 1 when only coefficients $\pm 1$ are used?

Comment: My construction was generic for $-1,0,1$ polynomials, we could have started with $x^3-x-1$, I haven't noticed that the example actually only requires $\pm 1$, that is nice catch. Also in this example it's easy to actually count and list all the roots, out of which there are precisely $2m+2$ distinct real roots given by $\sqrt[3^n]{\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}}$ for $n=0,1,\dots,m$ (roots taken in real numbers).